# How do you set value of an Ajax dynamically updated multiple chosen dropdown box using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dropdownbox

I have this chosen jquery dropdown box that shows the states/provinces when I click on a checkbox that is labelled Canada or another checkbox labelled United states.

I want to let my users have the option to remember their recent choices.  If they clicked on the Canada
checkbox and then clicked on a province  in the dropdown list.  I want to be able to choose the options again with through the click of some other button.

However, i'm not having much luck because the dropdown list of provinces is dynamically changed after the checkbox is set, and the elements in the dropdown list appear to be null.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: "dropdown list of provinces is dynamically changed after the checkbox is set" why not fire your code on a call back firing AFTER the list is populated?

Comment: Thanks for your reply atmd.  That definitely gives me a couple of ideas of solutions that I can try.  I'll give them a try and see what happens.